# AngularJS ng-repeat displays two dimensional array from Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

Here is html file, I want to show `2D` array from `json-$scope.listOfIngredient`

```
  <div class="ingredientMapping" ng-repeat="IngredientMapping in listOfIngredient track by $index">

      <ul>
        <!-- BEGIN: Inner ngRepeat. -->
        <li  ng-repeat="x in IngredientMapping.Ingredient">

            {{x.name}}

        </li>
        <!-- END: Inner ngRepeat. -->
    </ul>
      </div>
```

here is my **Controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController',function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.listOfRecipe = null;
    var url = "http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes.json";
    var url2 = "http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes/view/";
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: url

}).then(function (response) {
         $scope.listOfRecipe = response.data.recipes;

         var temp;
         for(var i=0; i<response.data.recipes.length;i++){
             $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: url2+ response.data.recipes[i].Recipe.id +".json"
                    }).then(function (response2) {

                        $scope.listOfIngredient = new Array(100);
                        for (var j = 0 ;j<100;j++)
                        {
                            $scope.listOfIngredient[i] = new Array(100);
                        }
                        for (var j = 0 ;j<response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping.length;j++)
                        {
                            $scope.listOfIngredient[i][j] = response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping[i];
                        }

                        console.log($scope.listOfIngredient);

                    });
         }



     })
```

Here is my Json file
http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes/view/id.json

```
here is error when I implement it and I know this error is from      $scope.listOfIngredient[i][j] = response2.data.recipe.IngredientMapping,
```

I got confused if it is correct to get 2d array like this way
[image]

Comment: So what is the issue here? are you unable to display the 2D array?

Comment: the issue is that I can not show the list of ingredient with a certain recipe id  on broswer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You currently have a hard-coded url from which you get a JSON representing recipies and their ingredients. You are able to display them in your console. Can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: I got all recipes from http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes.json,

Comment: I got all recipes from http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes.json,now I need to display a list of ingredients of each recipe on browser , the ingredients data of  each recipe is in http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes/view/id.json, "id" is recipe id. At moment, I can get 2d array of  ingredient in javascript(can be displayed on console), but it would not be able to be showed on browser(I guess something is wrong in my html , I checked my mapping is ok )

Comment: @Agnes, your mapping is not correct, and you are calling the incorrect nodes. If you look at my fiddle, it's your data, and with the corrected ng-repeat it displays the ingredients in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your mapping is off. This works for me:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="ingredientMapping" ng-repeat="recipes in listOfIngredient">
    <ul>
      <li  ng-repeat="x in recipes.recipe.IngredientMapping">
        {{x.Ingredient.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7841/

Edit:

so:

`<li  ng-repeat="x in recipes.recipe.IngredientMapping">` instead of

`<li  ng-repeat="x in IngredientMapping.Ingredient">`

and:

`{{x.Ingredient.name}}` instead of

`{{x.name}}`

Comment: Yes ,I did as you said and my mapping is ok, but still doesn't work

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController" class="center">   <div class="ingredientMapping" ng-repeat="recipes in listOfIngredient track by $index"><ul>
            <!-- BEGIN: Inner ngRepeat. -->
            <li  ng-repeat="x in recipes.Recipe.IngredientMapping">

                {{x.Ingredient.name}}

            </li>
            <!-- END: Inner ngRepeat. -->
        </ul>

Comment: Either remove the `track by $index` snippet, or make sure you are running Angular 1.2 as a minimum.

Comment: When you say, "it still does not work" - are there any errors in your console?

Comment: if I remove the track by $index snippet, it will show errors angular.js:12520 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=recipes%20in%20listOfIngredient&p1=undefined%3Aundefined&p2=undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:280:375
    at Object.fn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:130:67)

Comment: You can try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7841/ - I upgraded Angular version to yours, and added the `track by $index` back in. Keep in mind, the solution proposed only solves the issue your question mentioned. I do believe with the code provided by you, this is the reason and solution.

Comment: can you show me how did you get recipe data in js file, in your jsfiddle, you didn't show me how to use $scope and $http directives to get data.